# How to execute the OnMouseUp only if there isn't a Gesture recognized (Delphi for Android)?

Tags: android, delphi, events, gesture

We build using Delphi XE6 a cross-platform application. On Android (at least) the OnMouseUp is fired *before* OnGesture event. In OnGesture we have something like

```
  case EventInfo.GestureID of
    sgiLeft: NavigateNext;
    ...
```

How can we execute the code from OnMouseUp only if nothing from OnGesture is executed?

EDIT: "nothing from OnGesture is executed" means that "no matching case branch has been found" or "no gesture has been recognized".

Answer (score 0):

What does `nothing from OnGesture is executed` mean exactly? Does it mean that no matching case branch has been found?

In this case you can set a boolean flag variable in the OnMouseUp event handler, indicating that mouse up has occured. In the OnGesture event handler, check if the flag is set, and if it has not been set, invoke the required code here. Finding the right time/place for clearing the flag is a different problem.

Comment: Edited the question to make it clearer. Also, the OnGesture might be NOT executed at all if nothing from known gestures is recognized (regardless of my code), even if the OnMouseUp is fired.